# Python while loop not updating the DataFrame column calculations

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop

I am writing a python code where I have a condition which till the time it is true I want the calculations to happen and update the dataframe columns. However I am noticing that the dataframe is not getting updated and all the values are of the 1st iteration only. Can an expert guide on where I am going wrong. Below is my sample code -

'''

```
mbd_out_ub2 = mbd_out_ub1
mbd_out_ub2_len = len(mbd_out_ub2)
plt_mbd_c1_all = pd.DataFrame()

brd2c2_all = pd.DataFrame()
iterc=1

### plt_mbd_c >> this is the data frame with data before the loop starts

plt_mbd_c0 = plt_mbd_c.copy()
plt_mbd_c0 = plt_mbd_c0[plt_mbd_c0['UB_OUT']==1]


while (iterc < 10):        
    
    plt_mbd_c1 = plt_mbd_c0.copy()
    brd2c2 = plt_mbd_c1.groupby('KEY1')['NEST_VAL_PER'].agg([('KEY1_CNT','count'),('PER1c', lambda x: x.quantile(0.75))]).reset_index()
    brd2c2_all = brd2c2_all.append(brd2c2).reset_index(drop=True)

    plt_mbd_c1 = pd.merge(plt_mbd_c1,brd2c2[['KEY1','PER1c']],on='KEY1', how='left')
    
    del brd2c2, plt_mbd_c0
    
    plt_mbd_c1['NEST_VAL_PER1'] = plt_mbd_c1['PER1c'] * (plt_mbd_c1['EVAL_LP_%'] / 100)
    
    plt_mbd_c1['NEST_VAL_PER1'] = np.where((plt_mbd_c1['BRD_OUT_FLAG'] == 0),plt_mbd_c1['NEST_VAL'],plt_mbd_c1['NEST_VAL_PER1'] )
    plt_mbd_c1['SALESC'] = plt_mbd_c1['NEST_VAL_PER1']/plt_mbd_c1['PROJR']/plt_mbd_c1['NEWPRICE']

    plt_mbd_c1['C_SALES_C'] = np.where(plt_mbd_c1['OUT_FLAG'] == 1,plt_mbd_c1['SALESC'],plt_mbd_c1['SALESUNIT'])
    
    plt_mbd_c1['NEST_VAL_PER'] = plt_mbd_c1['C_SALES_C'] * plt_mbd_c1['PROJR'] * plt_mbd_c1['NEWPRICE']
    
    
    plt_mbd_c1['ITER'] =  iterc
    
    plt_mbd_c1_all = plt_mbd_c1_all.append(plt_mbd_c1).reset_index(drop=True)
           
    plt_mbd_c1.drop(['PER1c'],axis=1,inplace=True)
    
    plt_mbd_c0 = plt_mbd_c1.copy()
    
    del plt_mbd_c1
    
    print("iter = ",iterc)
    iterc = iterc + 1
```

'''

So above I want to take 75th percentile of a column by KEY1 and do few calculations. The idea is after every iteration my 75th percentile will keep reducing as I am updating the same column with calculated value which would be lower then the current value (since it is based on 75th percentile). However when I check I find for all the iterations the values are same as the 1st iteration only. I have tried to delete the data frames, save to temp data frame, copy dataframe but non seem to be working.

Please help !!

Comment: I am guessing you want to start with the same dataframe on every loop of the while loop:  `plt_mbd_c1 = plt_mbd_c0.copy()` ??

Comment: @ScottC Yes, and at every iteration it should have the updated values.